# How do you convert AVI to FLV using Avidemux in Windows?

Tags: avi, video-conversion, flv, avidemux

I've tried the tutorial but there seems to be a specific file that has to be associated with Avidemux. I'm using version 2.5.1 (r5249)

Comment: must it be Avidemux? you can use Pocked DivX Encoder instead: http://goo.gl/LS3C

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've just converted a video to FLV using Avidemux 2.5.2 on Ubuntu. While I realize that your question is about Avidemux on Windows, I think that they should work pretty similarly on both platforms. The key things were:

- Set the video codec to FLV1 (lavc)
- Set the audio codec to MP3
- Set the format to FLV

Answer (score -1):

AVI is a container that has video and/or audio tracks. FLV compresses both. You may find it easier to use Avidemux to convert (open) the AVI and then save as an MP4. Close Avidemux and open the MP4 you just saved and try finding the codec details (media info) of the source file in a video player. Here are some examples of how to open-convert-save. Windows XP SP3:

1. Open AVI in Avidemux (2.6.6) used here.
2. Video Decoder: lavcodec
3. Video Output: Copy
4. Audio Output: MP3 (lame)
5. Output Format: MP4 Muxer
6. File>Save

The output (MP4) file was almost the same size as the AVI.

The above worked for an AVI that would not convert to FLV1 Video Output with  settings at FLV1, MP3 Audio, and FLV Muxer.  My attempts to convert the saved MP4 to an FLV prove useless. Will edit or reply. Hope this helps-Milo

Comment: This is **not** an answer to the original question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post - you can always comment on your own posts, and once you have sufficient [reputation](http://superuser.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](http://superuser.com/help/privileges/comment).